# Cucumber 7.11.0 cant find feature files?

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, cucumber-junit, maven-failsafe-plugin

Im trying to use Cucumber 7.11.0 to run my feature files. But it doesn't seem to be able to find them. I am trying to run as part of the maven verify stage with maven-failsafe-plugin

Here is my test runner class:

```java
@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("features")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = PLUGIN_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "pretty")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "com.app.rs.api.cucumber")
public class TestRunner {}
```

My Project structure:

```
| /src
| - /test
| -- /java
| --- /com/app/rs/api/cucumber
| ---- /stepdefinition
| ----- StepDef.java
| ---- TestRunner.java
| -- /resources
| --- /features
| ---- test.feature
```

When I try to run my TestRunner I get the following error message

```
Internal Error occurred.
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-platform-suite' failed to discover tests
```

My pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>7.11.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit-platform-engine</artifactId>
    <version>7.11.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
   <version>5.9.2</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-suite</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M8</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>0</forkCount>
        <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
        <skip>${release}</skip>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
       <execution>
          <goals>
             <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
          </goals>
       </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to specify the path like:

*features="src/test/resources"* in *@SelectClasspathResource("features")*, if it is possible, coz in the older versions of Cucumber we have to use it like: @CucumberOptions(features="src/test/resources") so maybe the new version expects smth similar to this

Answer (score 0):

By using `@SelectClasspathResource("features")` you are instructing JUnit to tell the Cucumber Test Engine to look for tests in the `features` package on the classpath.

However your project does not follow the [Maven Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). When following this structure your classes should be under `scr/test/java`.

This means that either:

1. you have configured Maven differently and changed the configuration such that `src/test/resources` isn't copied to `target/test-classes`.
2. You are not using Maven to run your tests but an IDE instead. If so your IDE is not configured correctly and does not use the `src/test/resources` as a classpath root.

You can work around this by instructing JUnit to tell Cucumber to look for tests in a different location. You can find all the options for this in the [`org.junit.platform.suite.api`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.platform.suite.api/org/junit/platform/suite/api/package-summary.html) package. You could try `@SelectDirectories("src/test/resources")`.

Though you should probably fix your project structure. You can use the [cucumber-java-skeleton](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton) as an example.

Comment: It only seems to find the tests when I include `cucumber.features=src/test/resources/features` in junit-platform.properties But I would prefer to use @SelectClasspathResource annotation.

Comment: Then you'll have to fix your project structure and setup. If you do not fix that, you'll keep running into issues like this. You can use the `cucumber-java-skeleton` as an example.

Comment: Yes, I have updated to same structure as show in cucumber-java-skeleton. But still no success :(

Comment: Work in the other direction, start with the skeleton, run with Maven. Then in small steps make it like your project. Test before and after every change. Once it stops working you found one of your problems.

Comment: Oh, and don't use your IDE to run code. Use Maven from your terminal and use only Maven. If it works with Maven, but not your IDE then that's the problem.